# Can't call javascript file from my html page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to JavaScript and just want to put my JavaScript code in another file.

This is my html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>my badass page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" scr = "testing.js"></script>//this contains the function I want to call
</head>
<body id="body">
    <button type="button", onclick="showDate()">show the date</button>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the testing.js file:

```
function showDate() {
    alert ("this works")
}
```

I'm assuming that I just make a beginner mistake because it seems really common but I can't figure it out.

Comment: I think you just have to format your code properly. `scr`? `type="button",` <= a comma?. Etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the button to

```
<button type="button" onclick="showDate()">show the date</button>
```

and change scr to src

EDIT: source that works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>my badass page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="testing.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body id="body">
    <button type="button" onclick="showDate();">show the date</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i just changed that and it still says "Uncaught ReferenceError: showDate is not defined"

Comment: You changed scr to src also ? the source works for me, are you also sure that the file is testing.js ? and it is in the same directory ?

Comment: ya im going to move the file around, i think the scr was the problem.  thank you

Answer (score 5):

you spelled the 'src' attribute incorrectly on your  tag

you spelled it `scr`, it should be `src`

this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" scr = "testing.js"></script>
```

should be this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src = "testing.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick use of html validator such as  http://validator.w3.org/nu/  will uncover lots of problems in your code. Just copy paste and correct the errors.